# e.target.value on an input field ReactJs, how does it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

I'm at the end of this tutorial and I'm just not understanding how e.target.value works. Walk through the end of this tutorial and see the sample code that there is please. I'm newbie both to React and Javascript.

Comment: `e` is the event, which in this case is `change`, `target` is the element that triggered the event, which in this case is the `input`, and `value` is the value of the `input` element

Comment: I recommend to read https://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html .

Comment: A slightly confusing thing worth researching is the difference between e.target and e.currentTarget . Reading about the difference may help your understanding.

Comment: Thank you @Josan , it's more clear now. Thanks for the documentation Felix, I will read it. I will also see that Shammoo. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 14):

The `e` is the argument of an event handler you attach to a certain event on a certain component... in this case the `onFilterTextInput` event. Events are objects with certain properties, and `e.target` almost always represents a DOM element.

Thus `e.target.value` is the value property of some DOM element, in this case that means the text entered in the search input.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to handle multiple controlled input elements, you can add a name attribute to each element and let the handler function choose what to do based on the value of event.target.name.
By React DOC

Answer (score 0):

So, 'e' stands for event and target is the element that triggered the event.
I find pretty useful this explanation about the difference between event.target and event.currentTarget at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp)