# What is event.target.value in React exactly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I was able to implement an event handler in my simple React app and I wanted to understand event.target.value more deeply. I have a guess, but I wanted to ask others so I can confirm or modify any false understandings.

So... how are we able to even use event.target.value in React? Does event belong to the [Event Web API that I found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)? Or is it more of a React thing?

Here is my code for reference

```
import React from 'react';
import Display from './Display';

export default class Search extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { userInput: '' };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
  }

  updateInput(e){
    this.setState({userInput: e.target.value});
  }

  onSubmit(){
    const title = this.state.userInput;
    console.log(title)
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <label>
        Movie Search App
        <br></br>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.userInput} onChange={this.updateInput}/>
      </label>
      <br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" onClick={this.onSubmit}/>
        <Display />
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [e.target.value on an input field ReactJs, how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624780/e-target-value-on-an-input-field-reactjs-how-does-it-work)

Comment: See [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) gives you the element **that** triggered the event.

So, `event.target.value` retrieves the **value** of that element (an input field, in your example).

In React, `event`s are [SynthenticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), a wrapper around the browser’s native event. It has the same interface as the browser’s native event, including `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`, except the events work identically across all browsers.

---

#### Does event belong to the Event Web API that I found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)?

**No**, it is [`SynthenticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) that is a wrapper around the native `event`.

#### Is it more of a React thing?

**Yes**, it has the same interface as the browser's native `event` but has little different [attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#overview).

#### How do I access the browser's native Event in a React code?

In most cases, you don't need to. But you can use `nativeEvent` property of `SynthenticEvent` i.e. `event.nativeEvent`.

---

Comment: Why do I need target? Why not direct event.value?

Comment: @username_allowed That is how [Event Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_objects) are structured.